# Plotting a GLM Model

Tags: plot, prediction, glm

I am facing trouble with plotting the predictions of a glm model . When i run the below code, R draws up an empty plot.

## Logistic regression

```
  model2 = glm(as.factor(loan_status) ~ . , data = train , family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
  summary(model2)
```

### Prediction

`pred1 <- predict(model2,test,type = 'response')`

```
ggplot(data.frame(pred1), aes(pred1))
```

train dataset consists of categorical and numerical values

Call:
      glm(formula = as.factor(loan_status) ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
      data = train)

Appreciate any assistance 
Thank you

Comment: Please actually state what your problem is. Do you get an error? Incorrect/unexpected results? Either way: show it!

Comment: Sorry, some of text got deleted when i pasted this question. The problem is with plotting. I see an empty plot with no lines. The error on the console is "Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'. Please let me know if more details are needed. Thank you @Caesar